# Connecting from win7 to VirtualBox/CentOS/MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox 4.2.16 on Win7. 
There I have MySQL server in CentOS 6.4. 
Telnet from Win7 to CentOS is fine.

`mysql -u root -h 192.168.56.102 -p`
in CentOS is fine.

This is what I have in the user table:

```
mysql> select user, host from user;
+------+----------------+
| user | host           |
+------+----------------+
| mm   | 127.0.0.1      |
| root | 127.0.0.1      |
| mm   | 192.168.56.102 |
| root | 192.168.56.102 |
| mm   | localhost      |
| root | localhost      |
+------+----------------+

6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL status:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.13, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      14
Current database:   
Current user:       root@loc
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.6.13-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     192.168.56.102 via TCP/IP

/usr/my.cnf:

[mysqld]

log_bin
port = 3306
bind-address = 192.168.56.102

/etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.56.102 loc
```

Still, when I try to connect from Win7/HeidiSQL to root on 192.168.56.102 port 3306,
I get

> SQL Error (1130)... Host '192.168.56.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

CentOS firewall is down, but, as far as I understand, this is not a firewall isue...
Any ideas?

---

After some research, I resolved this issue.
   In the user table I have 3 entries for each user: 
   with host %, with host localhost, with host 192.168.56.101

This is achieved by the command
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'X' IDENTIFIED BY "pass" WITH GRANT OPTION;

where X = %, localhost, 192.168.56.101

This way the guest MySQL server can be connected both from the guest and from Win7 host.

Comment: This question seems more suitable for http://superuser.com rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Edit the `my.cnf` file (probably in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`). Look for the `bind-address` line and change the IP address to 192.168.56.102.

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure that mysqld runs on 192.168.56.102.

Comment: Oops... /usr/bin/my_print_defaults mysqld says that bind-address=192.168.56.102 And mysqladmin variables -p -h loc confirms this. What happens is that my rpm install used /usr/my.cnf and then I copied it /etc and rebooted. Nothing changed...

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/questions/637881/connecting-from-win7-to-virtualbox-centos-mysql/1745807#1745807